# how to create a new neural network model from a model with branchs (Python, keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just coded a model similar to this:
[image]

and this is the code:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Funcion que define la red siamesa
def createBaseNetwork(input_shape):
    weight_decay = 1e-4
    L2_norm = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)

    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    print(input)

    x = Conv2D(96, (9, 9), activation='relu', name='conv1', kernel_regularizer=L2_norm)(input)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(x)

    x = Conv2D(384, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2', kernel_regularizer=L2_norm)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(x)

    x = Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv4')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv5')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool3')(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)

    return Model(input, x)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def getSiameseNetWork(input_shape, numClasses):
    base_network = createBaseNetwork(input_shape)

    input_a = Input(shape=input_shape)
    input_b = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Reuso de la instancia para compartir los pesos
    left = base_network(input_a)
    right = base_network(input_b)

    # Concatenar con la red siamesa y generar capas adicionales
    outLayers = Concatenate(axis=-1)([left, right])
    outLayers = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dropout(0.2)(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name='fc3')(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dropout(0.2)(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='fc4')(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dropout(0.2)(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc5')(outLayers)
    outLayers = Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(outLayers)

    model = Model([input_a, input_b], outLayers)

    return model


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now i need to load the weights i just obtained from this into the same model, but using only one input.
So i tried something like this:

```
model=getSiameseNetWork(input_shape,numClasses)
newModel=Model(model.input,model.get_layer('predictions').output)
```

Thats it, but i doesnt work. I donk know how to get one of the branches an make a new model with that. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```
def network(X):
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=4)(X)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=4)(X)
    X = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(X)

    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=2)(X)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2)(X)
    X = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(X)

    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1)(X)
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1)(X)
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1)(X)

    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2)(X)
    X = layers.Flatten()(X)
    return X
```

```
a = 1100
X_input1 = layers.Input(shape=(a, a, 1))
X_input2 = layers.Input(shape=(a, a, 1))
X1 = network(X_input1)
X2 = network(X_input2)
X = layers.Add()([X1, X2])
X = layers.Dense(8)(X)
model = Model([X_input1, X_input2], X)
```

Comment: I have this already, now i want to run that network but using only one of the branches. I know that the secret is in the Model() method, but dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def newtork(X, inp):
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=4, name="conv_1_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=4, name="pool_1_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, name="batch_1_"+str(inp))(X)

    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=2, name="conv_2_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, name="pool_2_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, name="batch_2_"+str(inp))(X)

    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, name="conv_3_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, name="conv_4_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, name="conv_5_"+str(inp))(X)

    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, name="pool_3_"+str(inp))(X)
    X = layers.Flatten(name="flatten_"+str(inp))(X)
    return X

a = 1100
X_input1 = layers.Input(shape=(a, a, 1), name="input_1")
X_input2 = layers.Input(shape=(a, a, 1), name="input_2")
X1 = newtork(X_input1, 1)
X2 = newtork(X_input2, 2)
X = layers.Add()([X1, X2])
X = layers.Dense(8)(X)
model = Model([X_input1, X_input2], X)
print(model.summary())
```

here you can see that their is a unique name for each layer

```
_____
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1100, 1100,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1100, 1100,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 273, 273, 96) 11712       input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 273, 273, 96) 11712       input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_1_1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 68, 68, 96)   0           conv_1_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_1_2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 68, 68, 96)   0           conv_1_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_1_1 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 68, 68, 96)   384         pool_1_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_1_2 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 68, 68, 96)   384         pool_1_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 384)  921984      batch_1_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 384)  921984      batch_1_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_2_1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 15, 15, 384)  0           conv_2_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_2_2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 15, 15, 384)  0           conv_2_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_2_1 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 15, 15, 384)  1536        pool_2_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_2_2 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 15, 15, 384)  1536        pool_2_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_3_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 13, 13, 384)  1327488     batch_2_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_3_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 13, 13, 384)  1327488     batch_2_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_4_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 11, 11, 384)  1327488     conv_3_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_4_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 11, 11, 384)  1327488     conv_3_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_5_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 9, 9, 256)    884992      conv_4_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_5_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 9, 9, 256)    884992      conv_4_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_3_1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 4, 4, 256)    0           conv_5_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool_3_2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 4, 4, 256)    0           conv_5_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 4096)         0           pool_3_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 4096)         0           pool_3_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_8 (Add)                     (None, 4096)         0           flatten_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 8)            32776       add_8[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 8,983,944
Trainable params: 8,982,024
Non-trainable params: 1,920
```

Here we try trying to find out the index of the layer which we want to use

```
input_index = None
output_index = None
input_layer_name = "input_1"
output_layer_name = "flatten_1"
for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if layer.name == input_layer_name:
        input_index = idx
    if layer.name == output_layer_name:
        output_index = idx
```

Here we extracted the layer from model with help of index

```
branch_model_1 = Model(model.layers[input_index].input, model.layers[output_index].output)
branch_model_1.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1100, 1100, 1)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_1_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 273, 273, 96)      11712     
_________________________________________________________________
pool_1_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 68, 68, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_1_1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 68, 68, 96)        384       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 384)       921984    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_2_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 15, 15, 384)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_2_1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 15, 15, 384)       1536      
_________________________________________________________________
conv_3_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 13, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv_4_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv_5_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 256)         884992    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_3_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 4, 4, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4096)              0
```

Comment: I get tis error: ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(None, 96, 96, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Comment: because you re providing very small input shape 96x96  this model require 1100x1100.       OR.      You just have to remove strides attributes from layers, decrease the pool_size in MaxPooling2D layer use (2,2) pool_size

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work, i keep getting same error

Comment: finally your answer helped me, it was my fault i was doint it wrong